# Pyside2 Dialog exce_() cannot stop

Tags: python-3.x

I use pyside2 to test dialog, but the program below won't stop, I don't know why.
How to stop the exce_() function?

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class MyDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        buttons = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(
            QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok |QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel,
            QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
        buttons.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttons.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        layout.addWidget(buttons)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyDialog()
    result = win.exec_()
    print(result)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Use `win.show()` instead of `win.exec_()`.

## Explanation

In your code `win.exec_()` is showing the dialog and blocking main thread until you press **OK** or **Cancel** (or simply close the dialog).

From [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#exec):

> Enters the main event loop and waits until exit() is called, then returns the value that was set to exit() (which is 0 if exit() is called via quit()).

`app.exec_()` waits for `exit()` from `QDialog` but at the time it starts waiting there is no `QDialog` already so there's nothing that could trigger `exit()` method.